# File upload using Ajax

Tags: javascript, file-upload

can anyone guide me how to upload a file thorugh ajax

when users click on Upload, i'm opening a div and users click on submit button, i'm calling an ajaxfile

upload :

1) How can i get these values in javascript ?

**$name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
   $temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmpname'];**

so that i can pass to the ajaxfile and do the necessary functionality...

Am i going in a correct way ?

Thanq

Comment: What you actually want to do???? why you want to get values in javascript

Comment: my functionality is like that
Change pic link will open a div with respective upload inputs & uploaded...using ajax there

so that why i need those values to get in javascript...is there a way ?

Answer (score 0):

Make an ajax request to php script which returns these data.

http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html - tutorial about uploading files with ajax.